# How to get data of 12-month ago

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle database, I have this data in a table:

| person | category | month | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | A | Jun-1-2022 | 100 |
| Mary | A | May-1-2022 | 200 |
| John | B | Jun-1-2021 | 230 |
| John | A | Jun-1-2021 | 430 |

I need to add a new column into this table, called 'Same_month_last_year', which contains the data of same month last year. For example, John's data would be 430 for row 1.

I know a function in Oracle called ADD_MONTHS. but I'm new to programming (a finance student) and cannot seem to figure out how to use ADD_MONTHS to create this new column. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SUM` analytic function with a range window:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(profit) OVER (
         PARTITION BY person
         ORDER BY month
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING
                   AND INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING
       ) AS last_year_profit
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (person, month, profit) AS
SELECT 'John', DATE '2022-06-01', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mary', DATE '2022-05-01', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', DATE '2021-06-01', 430 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PERSON | MONTH | PROFIT | LAST_YEAR_PROFIT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | John | 01-JUN-21 | 430 | *null* |
> | John | 01-JUN-22 | 100 | 430 |
> | Mary | 01-MAY-22 | 200 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6380f9b16b0a9cdace5d771270fdaf3a)*

Comment: Thank you MT0! 
If there is another column that I also want to partition by, how do I do it? For example, in the sample data above, I added another column "category".

Comment: @Little_Tomato `PARTITION BY person, category`

Comment: Oh I think I figure it out now. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I tried it out and works fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can not have dynamically calculated columns in a table. You need to create a view and assign IDs to each person. Then in the view's script, the calculation of the new column will work like this:

```
(select profit
from table t
where
month = add_months(t.month, -6)
and id = t.id) as same_month_last_year
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Alright dear bot, I made it clearer.